# What does penalizing a function mean, and how is it implemented?

Tags: machine-learning, probability

I've alway seen this statement in academic papers, blog posts, documentation, etc. but I've never understood it. What does it mean to penalize a function, and what is a concrete example of it? Just to give an example, in a recent paper I've read, after taking the SVD of a matrix, they then used two functions to penalize the U and V matrices.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let's say you want to achieve a certain objective. For instance, you want to find $z_i$ that minimize the sum of squares: $$\sum_i(y_i-z_i)^2$$ where $y_i$ are given. In this case obviously $z_i=y_i$ would minimize the sum, in fact it would make it zero.

Now, what if we wanted to impose some other condition on $z_i$? For example, I'd like to *penalize* the length of the piece-wise linear curve that goes through $z_i$. The longer the curve, the higher is the penalty.

Here's how I could do it: change the objective to the following:
$$\sum_i(y_i-z_i)^2+\sum_i \sqrt{1+(z_i-z_{i-1})^2}$$

Now if you make $z_i\ne y_i$ then you can reduce the second term of the above objective a little more than increasing the first term, and the net effect would be lower objective than when $z_i=y_i$.

This is a general idea, and you can apply it to many situations such as SVD, where you're minimizing some kind of function too. You add a penalty to it, and get a different solution.